# Can i override layout id in support library?

Tags: android, layout, android-support-library

I want use custom view in BottomNavigationView from google support library.
I found where load view (android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView):

```
public BottomNavigationItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        final Resources res = getResources();
        int inactiveLabelSize =
                res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.design_bottom_navigation_text_size);
        int activeLabelSize = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.dimen.design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size);
        mDefaultMargin = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.design_bottom_navigation_margin);
        mShiftAmount = inactiveLabelSize - activeLabelSize;
        mScaleUpFactor = 1f * activeLabelSize / inactiveLabelSize;
        mScaleDownFactor = 1f * inactiveLabelSize / activeLabelSize;

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.design_bottom_navigation_item, this, true);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.design_bottom_navigation_item_background);
        mIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        mSmallLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smallLabel);
        mLargeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.largeLabel);
    }
```

Can i replace this layout without fork class? Replace design_bottom_navigation_item layout?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It's possible. Just put design_bottom_navigation_item.xml in layout folder.